# Using Gradient Descent on Exponentially Modified Gaussian

Tags: python-3.x, gradient-descent

I am trying to implement a gradient descent method to fit an EMG as shown in this [paper](https://analyticalsciencejournals.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/cem.1343). The paper describes two versions of the EMG equation:

(1)

$$F(t)= \frac{h\cdot\sigma}{\tau}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}e^{(\frac{\mu-t}
{\tau}+\frac{\sigma^2}{2\tau^2})}\cdot erfc(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\frac{\mu-t} {\sigma}+\frac{\sigma}{\tau}))$$

and

(2)

[F(t)= h\cdot e^{\frac{-(\mu-t)^2}{2\sigma^2}}\cdot \frac{\sigma}{\tau}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}} \cdot erfcx(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\frac{\mu-t}{\sigma}+\frac{\sigma}{\tau}))]

The paper defines z as:

[z = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\frac{\mu-t}{\sigma}+\frac{\sigma}{\tau}))"]

If z is negative equation (1) is used, otherwise equation (2) is used to prevent the function from blowing up. I'm implementing a batch gradient algorithm following the outline from this [site](https://towardsdatascience.com/gradient-descent-in-python-a0d07285742f), knowing my objective function is a bit different. I'm setting my theta as the following:

[\theta_j = [\mu, h, sigma, \tau]]

So my gradient update formula is the following:

[\theta_j^{k+1} = \theta_j^{k} - \frac{1}{m}\alpha\sum_{i=0}^{m} (F(t_i) - y_i)\frac{\partial F(t_i)}{\partial \theta_j^{k}}]

I've used wolfram alpha to determine all the partial derivatives. My total samples are >4000, so I'm used a batch of around 300 samples to speed up the process. I've found that I have to adjust the initial parameters very slightly to get the best results, otherwise the gradient will just blow-up.

The paper also discusses finding the time coordinate of the EMG Peak, which I'm not sure how the is useful in the gradient descent algorithm. It is found with the following:

[t_0 = \mu + y \cdot \sigma \cdot \sqrt{2}-\frac{\sigma^2}{\tau}]

where y is:

erfcx(y) = \frac{\tau}{\sigma}\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}

So my main questions are:

- Am I setting up the gradient descent incorrectly for a non-linear equation?
- How does the determination of the time coordinate help with the algorithm?

Please let me know if there is any additional information I can provide. The algorithm itself is each and I didn't want to clog up the post with my function definitions of each gradient.

Comment: The math equations I put in are not showing up in the right LaTeX format. Hopefully it works for others.

Comment: It also seems that stockoverflow does not allow equations. I'll post pictures of equations once I get 10 reputation. Sorry about that!